# Installing YASnippet

Tags: emacs, debian, yasnippet

I have installed YASnippet and configured it with this:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c")
(require 'yasnippet) ;; not yasnippet-bundle

(yas--initialize)
(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/packages/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets")
```

However, when I launch Emacs it gives me an error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/alexander/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: yas--initialize

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c")
(require 'yasnippet) ;; not yasnippet-bundle

(yas--initialize)
(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/packages/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets")
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to find the answer but with no success. (I have also tried with another version of yasnippet yasnippet-0.6.1b but it was the same.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just at a glance, that

```
(yas--initialise)
```

should be

```
(yas/initialize)
```

I'm running `0.6.1` and there's no such function as `yas--initialize` in the package.

My init code looks like

```
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas/initialize)
(yas/load-directory
 (dot-emacs "elpa/yasnippet-0.6.1/snippets"))
```

I think you just got some garbled init code somewhere.

**EDIT**

I should have omitted the `load-directory` call in my sample since it's beside the point.  But for what it's worth, `dot-emacs` is just a config-agnostic function I use to reference files relative to my init:

```
(defun dot-emacs (relative-path)
  "Return the full path of a file in the user's emacs directory."
  (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory relative-path)))
```

Comment: now it says "Symbol's function definition is void: dot-emacs"

Comment: @mr.axelander, I neglected to mention that `dot-emacs` is a custom function of mine.  The `yas/load-directory` code that you had should be fine.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Very nice answer (and thank you for the dot-emacs, as a noob it became a new addition of my .emacs ;-) )!

Comment: @Rick77, glad to hear that :) Although things are even simpler now.  If you get `yasnippet` through the package manager (`M-x list-packages`) and keep your snippets under `~/.emacs.d/snippets` (which it includes by default), no special configuration is necessary.  The only thing I do in init is `(yas-global-mode)`.

Comment: @harpo: thank you for the tip! I actually use the package manager already (found about it weeks ago, right because I had problem with yasnippet and autocomplete. I actually still do ;D), but for some reason unknown to myself I wanted to install my snippets in .emacs.d/my-snippets and I came here (for the records, the only thing that worked was to use `(yas/compile-directory (dot-emacs "my-snippets"))` before including the directory...). Thank you for the help anyway (the more I get to know emacs, the more it rocks ;-) )!

Answer (score 4):

FYI in case you ever upgrade: the information you got is correct for version `0.8`, but for `0.7` and below `yas/initialize` is correct.
See [this commit](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/commit/90cd855c14f92088067425381ea5225d8af8e6f0)

Comment: Yes, this had me confised for a while. I obtained the init.el code from the YAS site which said that I should use (yas/initialize) but that didn't work and produced the error Symbol's function definition is void: yas/initialize. I decided to give (yas--initialize) a try in init.el and that works for me.